# Customer Id not storing for rating in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, rating, review

When I'm trying to add reviews and rating I'm getting error like:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `rating_option_vote` (`option_id`, `review_id`, `percent`, `value`, `remote_ip`, `remote_ip_long`, `customer_id`, `entity_pk_value`, `rating_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

My code:

```
$review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                    ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                    ->setStatusId(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)    
                    ->setCustomerId((int)$customerId)    
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setStore(array($storeId))    
                    ->save();
                $rating=array(1=>1,6=>1,11=>1);
                foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
     Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
         ->setCustomerId((int)$customerId)
          ->setRatingId($ratingId)
          ->setReviewId($review->getId())
          ->setCustomerId((int)$customerId)
          ->addOptionVote($optionId, $review->getEntityPkValue())
//         ->save()
         ;
}
```

Any help appreciated.